# Check if string in string and extract it

Tags: php, regex

I got a string which may have 1-3 stars at the beginning. I want to check if there are stars and if this is the case, I need to extract them as a integer.

```
* Lorem ipsum
** Lorem ipsum
*** Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
```

Result:

```
array(1, 'Lorem ipsum')
array(2, 'Lorem ipsum')
array(3, 'Lorem ipsum')
array(0, 'Lorem ipsum')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$s = '*** Lorem ipsum';

if (preg_match('/^(\**) *(.+)$/', $s, $m)) {
    $out = array(strlen($m[1]), $m[2]);
    print_r($out);
}
```

**Output:**

```
array(
  0 => 3,
  1 => "Lorem ipsum",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
$text = <<<TEXT
* Lorem ipsum
** Lorem ipsum
*** Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
TEXT;

preg_match_all('/^(\**)\s*(.*)$/m', $text, $matches);
list(, $keys, $values) = $matches;

for ($i=0; $i < count($keys); $i++) 
    $result[] = [strlen($keys[$i]), $values[$i]];

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Lorem ipsum
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Lorem ipsum
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Lorem ipsum
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => Lorem ipsum
        )

)
```